# Image will not shrinkwrap to curved surface

Tags: image, shrinkwrap

This is the result I am getting from this image shrinkwrapped to the mug. The image has 200 loop cuts. I have tried other settings, such as project but most of them do absolutely nothing to the image.
[image]

[image: image I have attached]

**UPDATE:** If you look at the mug from the side you will see that the center markings on the road image are at different sizes. They are random sizes. Though they are gathering up and getting smaller as they go around the cylinder. None of the loop cuts are evenly distributed either.
[image]

Comment: From what I can see, it looks pretty much shrinkwraped on the screenshot. Perhaps you might need to send a screenshot with a more relevant angle

Comment: @Alex
I have amended the images to show a side view. Here you can see than randomness of the loop cuts when the shrinkwrap is applied and the affect it has on center lines which are all different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the wrap method to target normal project, it usually gives a better projection as you can see in these pictures

[image]

[image]

Also make sure the mug has enough resolution, the higher it is the more acurate the projection will be (it needs to have more resolution than the projected mesh)